# Can I create a Facebook sharer with a trackable link?

Tags: facebook

Like this? Right now, FB is stripping out the querystrings I'm using to track.

```
https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fpost%2F%3Fref%3Dfb-share
```

Comment: Facebook will use the `og:url` or canonical URL value of the URL you share as the “real” URL identifying the Open Graph object. If you want to share including tracking parameters, then you need to set those in `og:url`/canonical as well. But be aware that this will then be treated as a _different_ Open Graph object than the URL without those parameters, so likes and shares for those two URLs will be counted separately – not sure if that’s really what you want.

Comment: Apart from that, Facebook embeds a couple of tracking parameters themselves already, when users follow links from their newsfeed. Maybe look into those first, and see if they would already allow you to gather what data you are interested in on your end.

Answer (score 0):

Using web links ? 
You can redirect the user for another url, using ?redirect_uri=http://... 
Track them and redirect them again for where you want .
You can try to include variables at the url too, and query for shares, comments and likes of each url ex: ?rel=track1  .

But thats not the best option .

You should implement facebook sdk and login the users, asking for publish_actions permission,, then you need get the response of the share funcion, it will come with post_id field, but only if you login the users as i said before .

```
FB.ui({
  method: 'share',
  href: 'https://www.facebook.com/davidaugustusbarreiradias/',
}, function(response){});
```

If the post privacy is set to public, you can view it using the response IDs, if users post as public and if they dont delete it .

Please be more specific about what you want, and please show the code you are using .